# Pyside: How to use QInputDialog.getText

Tags: python-2.7, global-variables, pyside

I am new to PySide and I am trying to have a user enter some text. I want to then store it in a variable and use it in a search through a separate script that I have. The search script that I have parses though a text file looking for keywords that the user would have entered. First things first, I am trying to get the input text to store in a variable, and I'm testing to see if its stored by using a simple print statement.

As you will see below, I've set it up so that an input box pops up and the user enters some text. But then if I call the print outside of `showDialog` nothing prints. If I print within the `showDialog` it works fine. Why wont it print outside the function?

If there's a better way to do this please feel free to educate me.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn = QtGui.QPushButton('test', self)
        self.btn.move(20, 20)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input dialog')
        self.show()


    start = ''
    end = ''
    number = ''

    def showDialog(self):
        global start
        start = start, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'text',
                                               'Enter some text')
        global end
        end = end, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, "text",
                                         "Enter some text")
        global number
        number = number, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, "text",
                                                "Enter some text")

    # I'm trying to print out the text stored from the input variables.
    print start
    print end
    print number

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `start`, `end` and `number` variables don't have global scope. They are declared and printed in the class scope, which happens only *once*, when the class is created.

But in any case, it is generally a bad idea to use global variables. If you want to make the variables available to other methods, use instance attributes instead:

```
def showDialog(self):
    self.start, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, 'text', 'Enter some text')
    self.end, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, "text", "Enter some text")
    self.number, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getText(self, "text", "Enter some text")
    print self.start
    print self.end
    print self.number
```

**EDIT**:

Below is a simple demo showing how you might structure your program. This assumes you can import your search module and run one of its functions to get the search results.

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
# import mysearch

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.resultsBox = QtGui.QTextEdit()
        self.resultsBox.setReadOnly(True)

        self.startBox = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.startBox.setPlaceholderText('Enter Start')
        self.endBox = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.endBox.setPlaceholderText('Enter End')
        self.numberBox = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.numberBox.setPlaceholderText('Enter Number')

        self.searchButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Search')
        self.searchButton.clicked.connect(self.runSearch)

        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.resultsBox, 0, 0, 1, 4)
        layout.addWidget(self.startBox, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.endBox, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.numberBox, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.searchButton, 1, 3)

    def runSearch(self):
        start = self.startBox.text()
        end = self.endBox.text()
        number = self.numberBox.text()
        if start and end and number:
            self.resultsBox.clear()
            self.resultsBox.append('Start: %s' % start)
            self.resultsBox.append('End: %s' % end)
            self.resultsBox.append('Number: %s\n' % number)
            # run search script ...
            # results = mysearch.run(start, end, number)
            results = 'Hello World'
            self.resultsBox.append(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = Example()
    example.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hi Ekhumoro, Thank you for your response. But what I want to do is to be able to access the users inputs outside of the showDialog function. WIth the provided example I can still only access the users input within the Function. How can I access the users input outside of the function and class?

Comment: @user6534872. That doesn't make any sense in the context of the script in your answer. After the `Example` window closes, the program will exit. While the window is open, the only way to run other code is via user interaction - which means you must use methods of the class.

Comment: @user6534872. I think your current script is not structured correctly. The input boxes should all go in the main window. Once the user has entered the values, a search button should be enabled. When the search button is clicked, it will run your search script and the results will be shown in a text-box.

Comment: Thanks @Ekhumoro!!